# How to convert data types from one table to match that of another?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two datasets that share all of the same column headers, but not the same data types.  One dataset contains historical sales and the other contains daily sales. The daily sales table's data types change from day to day depending on whether certain columns contain a value.

I want the daily sales data types to match that of the historical sales, but I receive an error when the data types already match, because I force `NULL` values for blank records.

Here is a sample of my query:

```
SELECT FileType,
       ACDealerID,
       DealNumber,
       CustomerNumber,
       CAST(NULLIF(Birthdate, '') AS DATE) AS Birthdate,
       CAST(NULLIF(RetailPayment, '') AS DECIMAL) AS RetailPayment
FROM Daily_Sales

UNION ALL

SELECT FileType,
       ACDealerID,
       DealNumber,
       CustomerNumber,
       Birthdate,
       RetailPayment
FROM Historicals
```

Here is the error message I received today

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

I understand that the error is due to the Birthdate field in the daily sales already being a DATE data type, but sometimes the Birthdate field comes through as a string with blank values and I need my query to account for these changes from day to day.

Comment: What is the structure of your tables (*columns, data types??*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the empty string can not be cast to a date. But (the unfortunately named) [NULLIF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NULLIF_function.html) returns the first value if the two values match or NULL otherwise, which in your case returns the empty string when you want to return NULL.

Similar to what Joe Harris said, you can use a [CASE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html):

```
(CASE WHEN Birthdate='' THEN NULL ELSE Birthdate END)::DATE AS Birthdate,
```

[NVL|COALESCE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html) is supposed to be the inverse of NULLIF, but does not do what you want either.

Note: NULL and values that are already DATE types will cast to a DATE just fine.

```
select CAST('2016-12-12'::date AS DATE) d1, CAST(null as date) d2;
     d1     | d2
------------+----
 2016-12-12 |

select CAST('' as date) d3;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification—I switched to the CASE statement in lieu of the NULLIF function and it seems to be working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `CASE` to prevent the DB from trying to convert the empty string.

```
CASE WHEN Birthdate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CAST(Birthdate AS DATE) END AS Birthdate,
```